# Blender copy rotation constraints bugging out

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I am trying to rig a first person set of arms, but the bones in the forearm are acting strange. I made three bones parented to the large forearm bone, they have copy rotation constraints linked to the hand IK bone so that they will only copy its Y rotation. It works in the rest position, but after moving the hand IK bone and rotating it along other axes, it doesn't follow correctly.

Here it is working fine.

[image: Here it is working fine]

[image]

After repositioning the arm, it does this. It barely reacts to the hand Ik bone rotating along the Y axis, and instead reacts the the Z axis.

[image]

[image]

http://pasteall.org/blend/32837

Comment: Do you have something like object `a` is parented to object `b` which is parented to object `a`? This can cause some funky behavior.

Comment: The three small bones arm parented to the single one, from what I can tell all the other parenting is as it should be

Comment: mind posting your .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/32837

Comment: So you are wondering why it twists at the wrist like that?

Comment: yeah, because when it is straight down it deforms like it should, but after changing position it seems that the forearm bones refuse to follow the hand

Comment: After its moved the forearm bones rotate when the hand IK bone is rotated on the Z axis instead of the Y like when it started

Comment: try changing `Twist_01.R`'s constraint to  `World Space -> Local Space`. Then rotate the hand controller on the local `Y` axis. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried that, and it works in the new position, but not in the starting position. I'm not sure why its acting this way